# Can I write this type of program?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
Create or replace procedure p1(
      name in varchar2
)
Is
  Details1 emp%rowtype;
  Details2 dept%rowtype;
Begin
  If name in (select ename from emp)
  Then
    Select * into details1 from emp 
    where ename=name;
    dbms_output.put_line(details1.deptno||' 
    '||details1.ename);
  End if;
  If name in (select dname from dept)
  Then
    Select * into details2 from dept 
    where dname=name;
    dbms_output.put_line(details2.deptno||' 
    '||details2.dname);
  End if;
End;
```

If I call it as:

```
Exec p1('BLAKE')
```

I want output like:

```
Deptno          Ename
-----------    ------------
20              BLAKE
```

and if I call it as:

```
Exec p1('Sales')
```

I want output like:

```
Deptno          Dname
-----------    ------------
30              SALES
```

In my procedure i take in parameter variable, and by passing any name on this variable if that name is exist in my table columns then i want the data from that table.

I m giving one example:
When we write ronaldo in google , there is a information gives about ronaldo from football table(assume football is table and the name ronaldo is exist in football table).
When we write obama in google , there is a info gives about obama from america's president table....if we write any name and that name is exists on any tables column then i want the data from that table..

Comment: What problem are you having with your procedure? Are you getting a compilation error, or a runtime error, or wrong (or no) output? It would be helpful if you explained - by [editing your question] - what you are trying to do. It looks like you want to pass in a name and look for matching employees *or* departments, and show the department number wither way; which is a bit odd. And what happens if you more than one person with the same name?

Comment: I just want data from a table if the entered data is exist in one of my tables column.. thats all @Alex Poole

Comment: It's unclear from this context, though, what your actual problem is. What results _do_ you get? See [ask].

Comment: Actually oracle doesnt support subquery within if statement.. so can you suggest me another program for Conditions?? @jdv  condition is: 
I just want the data from a table if the entered data is exist in one of my tables column..

Comment: I think you ought to [edit] this question and be clear what you are asking. Someone who knows the answer may not be able to discern what your actual question is here, which does not mention subqueries at all. Did you read [ask]?

Comment: In my procedure i take in parameter variable, and by entering any name if that name is exist in my table columns then i want the data from that table.@jdv

Comment: It's best to not put details like this in comments as they can be removed. You can [edit] the question to clarify it.

Comment: whats wrong with this query it will check if a column has data for a table.. please explain ? Select column_name into col from user_tab_cols where table_name='table' and column_name ='data' .. and if col is not null do whatever u want

Comment: Actually subquery is not working in if statement. This is the problem. And how can i do a program with this condition.@Moudiz

Comment: Why does this have to be a procedure at all? Why not write it all simply in SQL? The only question I have - I am actually pointing out that your problem itself may not make sense - is that if the name is found as an employee, you want to return a column labeled ENAME, but if the name is found as a department, it must be in a column DNAME. What if the same name is found in both? What if you have a department `SALES` and an employee `John SALES`? What is the desired output? It would make more sense to have the output in THREE columns: deptno, name and classif (showing either DEPT or EMPL).

Comment: @Alex Poole did you get the question??

Comment: @Littlefoot ???

Answer (score 1):

Very hard to understand what you want as others have said but I believe what you want is something along the lines of the below, completly untested code so may have some syntax errors but at least gives you another idea to explore.

```
Create or replace procedure p1(name in varchar2) Is

  V_name varchar2(1000) default null;
  v_dept varchar2(100) default null;
Begin

  begin
    select ename, deptno
    into v_name, v_dept
    from emp
    where upper(trim(name)) = upper(trim(v_name));
  exception 
    when no_data_found then
       v_name = null;
       v_dept = null; 
    when to_many_rows then
       -- handle this however you need
  end;    

  If v_name is not null then
    dbms_output.put_line(v_deptno||' '||v_name);
  else
    begin
      select dname, deptno
      into v_name, v_dept
      from dept 
      where upper(trim(name)) = upper(trim(v_name));
    exception 
      when no_data_found then
         v_name = null;
         v_dept = null; 
    when to_many_rows then
       -- handle this however you need
    end;     
    If v_name is not null then
      dbms_output.put_line(v_dept||' '||v_name);
    End if;
  end if;
End;
```

Comment: If there is no of table like emp,dept,client etc and i pass the name through the parameter and if that name is exist in any of my tables column, then how can i retrieve the data from that particular table. As Above i have mentioned.@Shaun Peterson

Comment: @Tarunkumar that is exactly what my code is doing... checking the Emp table displaying if it exists, otherwise check the Dept table display if exists.... just expand to cover off any further tables.  if you want to make it cleaner move each select / exception into a function and just have a bunch of function calls eg get_person_details(name), get_dept_details(name) ect

Comment: Yeah.. Thank you @Shaun Peterson

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can come to something like what you describe is this:

A single SQL statement, taking a bind variable :name. Select from EMP and from DEPT; output a column with the department number, the name (which shouldn't even be needed, since it is the value used as input in all cases), and an additional column "type" to show whether the name was found in EMP or in DEPT. If you then must create a procedure from this, that part is trivial.

```
select  deptno, ename as name, 'EMPL' as classif
  from  emp
  where ename = :name
union all
select  deptno, dname, 'DEPT'
  from  dept
  where dname = :name
;
```

Comment: If there is 6-7 more table and i pass the name and that name is exist in no6 table then how can i retrieve the data from that particular table. As Above i have mentioned.